# How to select two desired columns in dataframe for building a svm model?

Tags: r, svm

I have a multi column data frame and I want to build an `svm` model. The question is how can choose two specific columns as data. For instance if my data frame is like this:

```
df <- data.frame("x1"=c(1,2,3),"x2"=c(4,5,6),"x3"=c(7,8,9),"x4"=c(1,0,1))
```

I want to build an `svm` model with x2 and x3 with respect x4.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `select` from `dplyr`, like this:

```
df <- select(df, x1,x2,x3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
library(e1071)
df <- data.frame("x1"=c(1,2,3),"x2"=c(4,5,6),"x3"=c(7,8,9),"x4"=c(1,0,1))

#SVM model
model <- svm(x4 ~ x2 + x3, data = df)
summary(model)

#Model predictions
pred <- predict(model, subset(df,select=c(x2,x3)))
print(pred)
```

Specifically, I think the `subset` function is what you are looking for:
`subset(df,select=c(x2,x3))`